# Need help proving an equation for y in a differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I found the answer for y in the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^2-1}{2}$$ and got $${y} = \frac{3+e^x}{3-e^x}$$ I am positive this answer is correct. My problem is I also have to prove it is correct by plugging it back in for y in the differential equation, and I did but ended up with a mix of x and y values in it and don't know the steps to get it just in terms of y so it can end up like the differential equation at the start. Steps from plugging the y equation back into y in dy/dx and then getting it in terms of why would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: By "1/2(y^2-1)" do you mean $$\frac1{2(y^2-1)}$$ or $$\frac{y^2-1}{2}$$

Comment: Didn't properly format it before because I haven't been on this site long so I didn't really know I was expected to do that but it is fixed now. And I meant it as $$\frac{y^2-1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct.  To put it back

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(3 - e^x)e^x -(3 + e^x)(-e^x)}{(3 - e^x)^2}$$
$$= \frac{3e^x - e^{2x} + 3e^x + e^{2x}}{(3 - e^x)^2}$$
$$= \frac{6e^x}{(3 - e^x)^2}$$

On the other han
$$\frac{y^2 - 1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}((\frac{3 + e^x}{3 - e^x})^2 - 1)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\frac{(3 + e^x)^2 - (3 - e^x)^2}{(3 - e^x)^2}$$
$$= \frac{6e^x}{(3 - e^x)^2}$$

Hence the answer is correct.